# Not able to initialize julia package repository

Tags: git, julia

While initializing package repository for julia, I'm getting following error

```
julia> Pkg.init() INFO: Initializing package repository /home/pauli/.julia/v0.5 
INFO: Cloning METADATA from https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
ERROR: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Net, SSL error: unknown error)  
in  macro expansion at ./libgit2/error.jl:99 [inlined]  
in clone(::String, ::String, ::Base.LibGit2.CloneOptions) at ./libgit2/repository.jl:191  
in #clone#109(::String, ::Bool, ::Ptr{Void}, ::Nullable{Base.LibGit2.AbstractCredentials}, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at ./libgit2/libgit2.jl:327  
in (::Base.LibGit2.#kw##clone)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.LibGit2.#clone, ::String, ::String) at ./<missing>:0  in (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##4#6{String,String})() at ./pkg/dir.jl:49  
in cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##4#6{String,String}, ::String) at ./file.jl:5
in init(::String, ::String) at ./pkg/dir.jl:47  in init() at ./pkg/pkg.jl:70
```

What I have tried so far

ran

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

and got same outcome as above.

Proxy is not as issue, since I can run git clone successfully.

Downloaded zipped git repo of metadata.jl and copied to $HOME/user/.julia/v0.5 and got following error

```
 ERROR: GitError(Code:ENOTFOUND, Class:Repository, Could not find repository from '/home/pauli/.julia/v0.5/METADATA')
 in Base.LibGit2.GitRepo(::String) at ./libgit2/repository.jl:11
 in init(::String, ::String) at ./pkg/dir.jl:40
 in init() at ./pkg/pkg.jl:70
```

How can I resolve this problem? where should I place this metadata.jl folder?

Comment: did you put the it here `/home/pauli/.julia/v0.5/` or here `/home/pauli/.julia`?

Comment: I put it in $HOME/user/.julia/v0.5. so the direrctory structure would be $HOME/user/.julia/v0.5/METADATA.jl

Comment: It's difficult to know without more details about your system and how you installed julia in the first place. I would suggest a) adding those here and/or b) filing an issue on the julia github page with all of the relevant details.

Comment: I'm  on ubuntu xenial. I used the repos provided by official julia installation page for linux. Finally, I got it working few hours before.

Answer (score 0):

Pkg.init(*alternate METADATA.jl repository URL*, *optional branch name*) is used when you have a METADATA repository that differs from the one most people use most of the time.  It is necessary for the alternate METADATA repository to exist and to be specified as the first argument to Pkg.init(). `Pkg.init()` with no arguments does not give the location of an alternate METADATA repository.  The documentation is available at [Custom METADATA Repository](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/packages/#custom-metadata-repository).

If you are developing a new package, an easier way may be to use 
    Pkg.generate("NewPackageName","MIT")
That will create the appropriate scaffolding under, in this case, (machine specific path)/.julia/v0.5/NewPackageName and you can start coding in that directory. Your package will not become known to anyone else until you choose to register it.  See the documentation [Generating a package](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/packages/#generating-the-package).

You do not need to download a copy of the default METADATA.jl. Installing Julia and frequently doing `Pkg.update()` takes care of that for you.  If your whole configuration is garbled, it is better to remove (delete) it and reinstall Julia.

Comment: Actually, I needed to install IJulia kernel for jupyter. Running Pkg.add("IJulia") was giving me above errors. After deleting $HOME/user/.julia, I ran Pkg.init() to initialize the local repo for package installation(). After cloning METADATA repo using git clone directly into .julia folder, I got it working. My directory structure for julia  packages is $HOME/user/.julia/v0.5/(metadata and other packages).

Comment: Thank you for including your solution.